# Python: splitting dictionary into smaller dictionaries by keys (tuple)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where keys are tuples of two integers `(x,y)` and values are strings.

How do I split this dictionary up into smaller dictionaries, where the split is determined by whether the `y`-value is greater than some treshold?

For example, say I have the keys (the dictionary values are irrelevant so I omit them here)

`(0, 2), (0, 4), (0, 10), (0, 3), (0, 11), (0, 20), (0, 8), (0, 14)`

and say I have the tresholds `0, 5, 10, 15`.

Then, one split should consist of a dictionary with the following keys:

`(0,2), (0,4), (0,3)`

since the y-values are all greater than 0, but not greater than 5.

Then the next dictionary should have keys

`(0,8)`

since it is greater than 0 and 5, but not greater than 10.

Then we have `(0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 14)`

since it is greater (or equal to) 0, 5, 10, but not 15.

Finally, we have `(0, 20)` by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), iterate and update keys determined by the bucket boundaries. This is a better idea than creating a variable number of variables.

```
d = {(0, 2): 1, (0, 4): 2, (0, 10): 3, (0, 3): 4,
     (0, 11): 5, (0, 20): 6, (0, 8): 7, (0, 14): 8}

L = [0, 5, 10, 15, float('inf')]  # include infinite to facilitate later comparisons

from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in d.items():
    for i, j in zip(L, L[1:]):
        if i <= k[1] < j:
            dd[i].update({k: v})
            break

print(dd)

defaultdict(dict,
            {0: {(0, 2): 1, (0, 3): 4, (0, 4): 2},
             5: {(0, 8): 7},
             10: {(0, 10): 3, (0, 11): 5, (0, 14): 8},
             15: {(0, 20): 6}})
```

The algorithm can be improved by using `bisect` instead of iterating the boundaries in `L` sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this can be written much better, but you should get the idea.  Just iterate through the dict, and check the y value of the key against various conditions that you can define or generate dynamically.

```
thing = {
    (1,2): 'a',
    (2,19): 'b'
}

d1 = {}
d2 = {}
for k, v in thing.items():
    // while iterating through the original dict, write some logic to determine how you want to split up based on the y values.
    if k[1] < 5:
        d1[k] = v
    if k[1] < 10:
        d2[k] = v

print(d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
original_dict = {(0, 2):"a", (0, 4):"b", (0, 10):"c",
 (0, 3):"d", (0, 11):"e", (0, 20):"f", (0, 8):"g", (0, 14):"h"}

thresholds = [0, 5, 10, 15]
thresholds = sorted(thresholds,reverse=True)
new_dict_of_dicts = {} #threshold: dict
for threshold in thresholds:
    new_dict_of_dicts[threshold] = {}
    for key in list(original_dict.keys()):
        if key[1] > threshold:
            new_dict_of_dicts[threshold][key] = original_dict.pop(key)

print(new_dict_of_dicts) 
#{15: {(0, 20): 'f'}, 10: {(0, 11): 'e', (0, 14): 'h'}, 5: {(0, 10): 'c', (0, 8): 'g'}, 0: {(0, 2): 'a', (0, 4): 'b', (0, 3): 'd'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method seems easiest to me, though it is certainly not the fastest:

```
d1 = {(k1,k2):v for (k1,k2),v in d.items() if 0<k2<=5}
d2 = {(k1,k2):v for (k1,k2),v in d.items() if 5<k2<=10}
d3 = {(k1,k2):v for (k1,k2),v in d.items() if 10<k2<=15}
d4 = {(k1,k2):v for (k1,k2),v in d.items() if 15<k2}
```

Or combine like so:

```
bounds = 0, 5, 10, 15, 1_000_000
bounds_dicts = {(b1,b2):{(k1,k2):v for (k1,k2),v in d.items() if b1<k2<=b2}
                for (b1,b2) in zip(bounds[:-1],bounds[1:])}
```

Again, this will be inefficient. The dictionary is being iterated over once for each new dictionary. But for small problems, this should be fine.