# Split dictionary into 2 dictionaries by specifying which key-value pair is to be inserted in new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose there is a  dictionary as follows:

```
d={'name': 'xyz', 'age':21, 'contact':2398402093, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87}
```

I need to divide them into 2 dictionaries where the second one contains name and contact and the first one contains the rest.

This is what I need:

```
d={'age:21, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87}
d1={'name':'xyz','contact':2398402093}
```

EDIT:

I tried splitting them based on length though I specifically want to split it based on the keys but even with length I get this error:

```
d={'name': 'xyz', 'age':21, 'contact':2398402093, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87} 
d1 = dict(d.items()[len(d)/2:])
d2 = dict(d.items()[:len(d)/2])
print(d1)
print(d2)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-66f097c85c58> in <module>
      1 d={'name': 'xyz', 'age':21, 'contact':2398402093, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87}
----> 2 d1 = dict(d.items()[len(d)/2:])
      3 d2 = dict(d.items()[:len(d)/2])
      4 print(d1)
      5 print(d2)

TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I split it based on the keys I want to put in the different dictionaries?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560160/python-splitting-dictionary-into-smaller-dictionaries-by-keys-tuple)

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Your dictionary definition isn't valid Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) to get the value and also delete the key in a single operation:

```py
d = {"name": "xyz", "age": 21, "contact": 2398402093, "address": "new_street", "score": 87}

keys = ["name", "contact"]

d1 = {}
for key in keys:
    d1[key] = d.pop(key)

print(d)
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
{'score': 87, 'address': 'new_street', 'age': 21}
{'name': 'xyz', 'contact': 2398402093}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a generator function to `pop` the entries of interest from the dictionary:

```
d1 = {'name':'xyz', 'age':21, 'contact':2398402093, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87} 

def fun(d, pop):
    for i in pop:
        yield (i, d.pop(i))
```

---

```
d2 = dict(fun(d1, ['age', 'contact']))

print(d1)
# {'address': 'new_street', 'name': 'xyz', 'score': 87}

print(d2)
#  {'age': 21, 'contact': 2398402093}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'name': 'xyz', 'age':21, 'contact':2398402093, 'address': 'new_street', 'score':87}                                                                                                                                                               

keys = {'name', 'contact'}                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

d1 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k in keys} 

d2 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in keys}   

d1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{'contact': 2398402093, 'name': 'xyz'}

d2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{'address': 'new_street', 'age': 21, 'score': 87}
```